# multiple $ne in $and query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to run a MongoDB Query in which I want to exclude specific documents.

my data is like this,

```
db.getCollection('tests').insertMany([
    { id: 1, make: "Honda" , model: "A1"}, <- this should be exclude
    { id: 1, make: "Honda" , model: "A2"},
    { id: 1, make: "Honda" , model: "A3"},
    { id: 1, make: "Hero" , model: "A4"},
    { id: 2, make: "Honda" , model: "A1"}, <- this should be exclude
])
```

I want to exclude the data which has `{ make: "Honda" }` and `{ model: "A1" }`.

I tried,

```
db.getCollection('tests').find({
  $and: [ 
    { id: 1}, 
    { make: {$ne: "Honda"} }, 
    { model: {$ne: "A1"} } 
  ]})
```

but it excludes all the documents with `{make: "Honda"}`

Comment: "I want to exclude the data which has { make: "Honda" } and { model: "A1" }. so it should return all the documents except the first one." ... but your last document with `id: 2` also has `make: "Honda" , model: "A1"`.  Your find logic returns `{ id: 1, make: "Hero" , model: "A4"}` https://mongoplayground.net/p/uhd_VBgeKbs

Comment: my bad, now edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.collection.find({
  $or: [
    {
      make: {
        $ne: "Honda"
      }
    },
    {
      model: {
        $ne: "A1"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": {
        $ne: 1
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

This should do the job,

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aLRPh6yT3-d)